# Inheriting from a generic constrained interface in Java

Tags: java, generics

For my homework we are supposed to implement a double linked list and the elements within that list, by overriding a given generic interface. Due to me not knowing my way around Generics or Interfaces, I am currently unsure how to even ask what I'm doing wrong.

To me especially the constrained generic in the parent class is confusing, as in how do I properly inherit from it and do I need to explicitly include the generics in the child class definition?

We were given:

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    public interface ListInterface<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Iterable<T> {

        //Some methods

    }
```

My attempt to implement the List and the Nodes of the List:

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    public class List<E extends Comparable<E>> implements ListInterface<T extends Comparable<T>> {

        private ListItem<E> head;
        private ListItem<E> tail;


        //List Constructor

        public List(){//standard constructor initializes empty List
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
        }

        //Helper class, encapsulates Node of Linked List

        private class ListItem<E extends Comparable<E>>{

            private E value;
            private ListItem previous;
            private ListItem next;

            public ListItem(E value){
                this.value = value;
            }

        }

    //Overriding Some methods

        public static void main(String[] args){
            List asdf = new List();
        }
    }
```

I've probably butchered quite a lot, in my attempt to get things to run, but most important for me would be to know how would I correctly inherit from the parent Interface, and how and why I need to define the generics in my class.

Currently the compiler is throwing a slew of errors the most relevant seeming to be:

```
AuDList.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public class AuDList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements AuDListInterface<T> {
                                                                          ^
```

and a variety of "> expected", "; expected" and "illegal start of expression"

I am more or less confident in how I'd implement the individual methods of the List, but neither RTFM nor searching the internet lead me to an answer which seemed relevant.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply do it `class List<E extends Comparable<E>> implements ListInterface<E>`!

Comment: Additionally, with the declarations `ListItem previous` and `ListItem next` you are using _raw types_. You should use `ListItem<E>` as the type!

Comment: Third ... As the `private class ListItem` is an _inner class_, it should not use the same type variable again. Better yet, make it `static`!

Comment: Last (but not least) ... Your error message complains about the class `AuDList` and mentions the interface `AuDListInterface`, which does not correspond to your shown code!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose To your last comment yes, only forgot to change that between copying.

Correct me if I misunderstood something but:

I should give the same Type placeholder to the Interface I'm inheriting from and the child which is inheriting, though the relevant constraints on the type should be defined in the child Generic...thing.

vielen dank :D

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose why dont you put it as answer :)

Comment: This surely must be a duplicate (can't find it right now).